# Empty() input by clicking on a button

Tags: jquery

How by clicking on `img-delete` I can remove the content in the input text with toto name ?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="toto">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li><a href="#" class="img-preview">Preview </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="img-change">Change</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="img-delete">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using actually:

```
$('.img-delete').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
});
```

It works but it delete all the input...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than selecting all the `input` elements within the closest `form` element, you could select the `input` elements within the closest `.input-group`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xL479u6w/)

```
$('.img-delete').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find("input[type=text]").val("");
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could select the input element based on the `name` attribute:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kxzabs0v/)

```
$('.img-delete').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find("[name='toto']").val("");
});
```

---

If neither of those options meet your needs, you would have to select the closest `.input-group-btn` element and then select the previous `input` element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgwwt5wt/)

```
$('.img-delete').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.input-group-btn').prev(':input').val("");
});
```

Comment: I took the first one and it works. I will accept the answer soon. Thanks.